# Solving a system of functional equations related to the identified minimum

Tags: probability, functional-equations

Define $g_0(x)$ and $g_1(x)$ so that $$g_0(x) = f(x)\cdot [1-F(x + \delta)] \\ g_1(x) = f(x-c)\cdot[1-F(x-\delta)],$$ where $f(x) = F'(x)$. I know that $F(x)$ is a cdf. Can one can uniquely solve for $F(x)$, $c$, and $\delta$ given knowledge of $g_0(x)$ and $g_1(x)$, at least under certain conditions? Any pointers on how to approach this problem would be useful.

**Context:** It is known that if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are independent random variables, then the distribution of each $X_i$ can be uniquely determined from the joint distribution of the minimum value of $\{X_i\}$ and the identity of the minimum [1] (the problem of the "identified minimum"). The above question is a variant of this problem. Suppose that $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are iid, $X_i = c_i + Y_i$ (for real numbers $c_i$), and we observe $(X_i, i)$ if $u_i - X_i \ge u_j - X_j$ for all $j \neq i$. The above equations come from the case where $n = 2$, $c_1 = u_1 = 0$, $\delta \equiv u_2 - c_2$, and $F(\cdot)$ is the cdf of $Y_i$.

[1] https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.1970.10488742

Comment: It's just an idea because I haven't worked out the details, but you might be able to use the (generalized) Fourier transform to extract $c$ and $\delta$ and change the derivative into multiplication by $ix$. $F$ should be a tempered distribution, at the very least it is if there's no atom in which case $F$ is continuous, and bounded, so the Fourier transform exists in the sense of distributions and behaves like you'd expect. It would introduce convolutions in lieu of multiplications though, which might not be pleasant nor ideal...